# check for Windows version in [Run] segment of InnoSetup config file

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, driver, inno-setup

I have to install a driver during my installation process in `InnoSetup`. For that I have two *.msi* installation files for 32bit/64bit. Now in Win7, this driver is already included, so I don't need to install it again. So far, I did this:

```
[Tasks]                
Name: "install_usb"; Description: "Install USB driver"; GroupDescription: "Drivers:";

[Files]
Source: "xy\driver\*"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Run]    
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\driver_32bit.msi"""; StatusMsg: "Installing 32bit USB driver"; Check: not IsWin64(); Tasks: install_usb; Flags: skipifsilent
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\driver_64bit.msi"""; StatusMsg: "Installing 64bit USB driver"; Check: IsWin64(); Tasks: install_usb; Flags: skipifsilent
```

So, the user can choose if he wants to install the driver. If he has chosen to do so, the correct driver runs. This works fine. Now I want to choose to not install the driver if >=Win7 is running. I read about `OnlyBelowVersion: 6.1` but I seem to be unable to do something like this in the `[Run]` section:

```
[Run]    
... Check: IsWin64() and OnlyBelowVersion:6.1; ...
```

**How can I use `OnlyBelowVersion` (or something similar) in the `[Run]` section?**

**Also, I want to make sure that the *.msi* is run in the proper mode (64bit mode for 64bit systems).** Because I think, that is not the case right now. Is it possible to enforce that? I found out about `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64`, where do I have to put that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`OnlyBelowVersion`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_commonparams.htm#OnlyBelowVersion) parameter you can't use in [`Check`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm) statement, but as a separate parameter.

```
[Run]    
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\driver_32bit.msi"""; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.1; StatusMsg: "Installing 32bit USB driver"; Check: not IsWin64(); Tasks: install_usb; Flags: skipifsilent
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\driver_64bit.msi"""; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.1; StatusMsg: "Installing 64bit USB driver"; Check: IsWin64(); Tasks: install_usb; Flags: skipifsilent
```

To you second question, the [`IsWin64`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_iswin64.htm) function returns True on all 64-bit editions of Windows, so that's what you have correct. From the reference:

> This function will always return True on an x64 edition of Windows.

To run your InnoSetup installation in 64-bit mode you've correctly mentioned, that you need to specify at least the [`ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode) directive. If you specify this directive with at least one of the available values, your setup will run in 64-bit mode on machines with the processor architecture(s) you specify, in 32-bit mode if you run your setup on machine with x86 processor.

Comment: Cool, that works perfectly. For the second question: While yes, this returns true in a x64 edition, does it also guarantee that the executables and the installer is run in 64bit mode?

Comment: Oh, I thought you want just the `driver_64bit.msi` installer to run on 64-bit systems, not the InnoSetup installer itself. Then I'll update the answer...

Comment: Well, the driver is the important part. But if it is not difficult to also include the installer itself in this condition, then that's a good thing.

Comment: I've updated my answer, even in this case you were right. If you want to run the InnoSetup installer in 64-bit mode on 64-bit processor architecture, specify the processor architecture(s) in `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` directive. On x86 architectures, the setup will run in 32-bit mode.

Comment: You should only use `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` if your actual application is 64-bit.  If only one component (such as a driver) is 64-bit then you should use the 64-bit path/registry constants and/or the `64bit` flag for the specific entries instead.